# Create table using variables as column names

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to build a database manager with appealing GUI for specific functions. One of the functions is to create a TABLE from a list of variable, where each element is one of the variable. Like this:

```
<?php 

include('conn.php');

var[0]='clients';
var[1]='id int(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY';
var[2]='name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL';
var[3]='surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL';

$create = "CREATE TABLE var[0] (
rest of vars
)";

...
?>
```

Really stuck here, guys.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @Strawberry, it probably is a bad idea, but I don't see any other way of giving user a flexibility of adding new tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

$var[0]='clients';
$var[1]='id int(4) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY';
$var[2]='name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL';
$var[3]='surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL';

$create = "CREATE TABLE $var[0] (
  $var[1],$var[2], $var[3]
)";


...
?>
```

Moreover, to add those $vars dynamically instead of manually you can do something like this:

```
$create = "CREATE TABLE $var[0] (";
for($i = 1; $i < count($var) - 1; $i++){
  $create.= $var[$i].",";
}
$create .= $var[$i].")";
```

Now you can execute the $create string as query;

Comment: This would probably work, but I would like to no have to list all variables manually.

Comment: small typo as `$var[i]` should be `$var[$i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be like this:

```
$tableName = array_shift($var);
$columns = implode(', ', $var);

$create = "CREATE TABLE {$tableName} ({$columns}))";
```

And also it would be a much cleaner approach.